# $\nabla f \ne 0$ then level curve of $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $f$ is parametrizable as a $\mathcal{C}^1$ curve.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ an open set and a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\nabla f \ne 0$ on $U$. For fixed $k \in f(U)$, put $C$ as following:
$$ C = \{(x,y) \subseteq U| f(x,y) = k\} $$

Is there any surjective $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $\gamma: [a,b] \to C$?

I believe that this problem is relative to implicit function theorem but I don't know how to prove...

++ For example, let $U = \{(x,y)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2|1<x^2 + y^2 < 9\}$ and $f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2$, $C = \{(x,y) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2|f(x,y)=4\}$. Clearly $\nabla f = (2x, 2y) \ne 0$ on $U$ but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ can be zero. So there is no function $g$ such that $C$ is the image of $(x, g(x))$ on $[-2, 2]$. Actually, $(2\cos t, 2\sin t)$ on $[0, 2\pi]$ is one of possible parametrization. I'm wondering if those parametrization generally exists.

Comment: You have $a$ in two different places.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I edited it.

Comment: There's no reason to think that $C$ will be compact. For example $f(x,y) = x$ on $U=\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: Oh, then is it impossible to hold under restricted condition that $C$ is compact?